# REST API Call gets called multiple times every 20 seconds

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis-7, http-post

Unfortunately i cannot share the code but the main issue here is that a device calls the API which takes longer than 20 seconds to process which results in the call being made again from the back-end. I have confirmed that it is not the device making a second call.

According to the following article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/338142/RESTful-API-in-WCF-get-called-more-than-one-time-b

> something which i found is that IIS has some setting for HTTP GET as
>   40sec replay, so if within 40sec if server does not get response it
>   again query itself.

In my case it is 20 seconds.

From that article i suspect that IIS is the culprit. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: So does the fix mentioned in the linked article - *Then I, change that API to WebInvoke (Http POST) and it worked!!* - not also work for you?

Comment: I am using a [HttpPost] now but that did not work.

Comment: *I have confirmed that it is not the device making a second call* - how have you confirmed this?